# Android ADT Eclipse (Juno) How to apply Dark UI Theme?

Tags: android, eclipse, themes

Hello I downloaded the Android ADT (Eclipse)

I have found this theme:
https://github.com/rogerdudler/eclipse-ui-themes

The instructions provided are as follows:

---

Download the ZIP package and extract it into your eclipse dropins folder:

https://github.com/downloads/rogerdudler/eclipse-ui-themes/com.github.eclipsecolortheme.themes_1.0.0.201207121019.zip

Restart Eclipse and go to Preferences > General > Appearance and choose Dark Juno

---

I have done that, restarted eclipse, but when I go to Windows -> Preferences -> General and then click on "Appearance" I get the following error message:

> Title: Could Not Accept Changes
>   Message: The currently displayed page contains invalid values.

Even if I didn't do that I still get this error

Comment: this should be a bug of ADT.see here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41126

Comment: @nut Thanks for the link. Do you know if it has been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Got this fixed after updating   Eclipse Color Theme plugin to   0.13.1.20140504130